# How to obtain a certificate request from an existing certificate

Tags: linux, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I've got a server where a .p12 is on it that has been converted to a .pem (files: certserver.p12, certserver.pem, certserver.pass for the password).

I now got a request to make a new certificate-request so that the certificate guys at my work can create a new certificate for me with an extended duration.

My problem is, using keytool and openssl I'm only finding infos on how to create new certificates from scratch but not on how to use the p12 or pem in combination with the pass to create a new request (that also includes the alternate dns names).

What parameters must I use there?

Comment: You will need the private key to generate a certificate request.  You don't state that you have one.  Also, what version of OpenSSL are you using?

Comment: You can use openssl to make "certificate **signing** requests", i.e. an existing certificate (yours) is signed by a "higher" certificate (the certificate guys at your workplace). So ask them if they mean that. Also, companies often have a general ticket system to make requests for certificates, but that has nothing to do with openssl. Again, ask them if that is what they mean.

Comment: @garethTheRed He said he has a .p12, so he has the private key.

Comment: @Thomas So your goal here is to fill in the signing request with as much existing information from the existing cert as possible, so you don't have to re-type it?

Comment: @spiff - Not necessarily as, although unlikely, you can have a cert only or even an empty PKCS#12 as its just a key store.  The OP stated he had everything bar the private key, so I queried this.  By the sound of it, the OP is attempting to extend the validity of the original certificate - not simply avoid re-typing into a new request with a new key.